# tar command: what is dash for?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

Can someone help me understand this command:

`tar -czf - -T ./tarFileList.tmp -C ./test_folder/ | ssh -l musthero voserver95.myserver.com -x "umask 002; cd /disk0/test_untar/ ; tar -xzf - "`

In particular, I can't understand what is the first dash for (`tar -czf - ...`).Why do I need it if I have specified list of files I would like to tar (i.e. `-T ./tarFileList.tmp`), and a directory where to take those files from (i.e. `-C ./test_folder/`).

Also copying is a bit confusing too - how the tarball gets copied over ssh if there is no `cp/scp` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The very first dash is unnecessary, you could equally write:

```
tar cvf ...
```

The second dash belongs with the `f` option and it says "instead of creating a named file in the filesystem, write the tarred up files onto `stdout`".

That `stdout` is then passed through the pipe into `ssh`. The corresponding untar on the remote machine is untarring from its `stdin` in exactly the same way.

So, in answer to your question, the dashes mean `stdout` when creating/writing a tarfile with `tar cf` and `stdin` when extracting/reading a tarfile with `tar xf`

Comment: OK! So dash is equal either to stdout _or_ stdin depending on whether I create _or_ extract a tarfile. Thanks!